Inject HTML into React using dangerouslySetInnerHTML
I am using React and fetching custom HTML headers and footers to be rendered above and below the main part of the React App (portal). These headers and footers are custom HTML and could be incomplete HTML on their own (but combined they would create complete HTML). The header and footer are really just HTML that go before and after the portal (not actual header and footer elements). For example the header may end in an opening tag like <main> and the footer could begin with the closing tag </main> with the portal nested inside.
I have tried to use React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but it seems like the browser is closing all the tags and not putting the portal in the proper location. For example instead of the header ending in <main> it ends in <main></main>. The header, portal, and footer are all on the same level hierarchy in the DOM, instead of the portal being nested between the header's opening tag and the footer's closing tags.
basic example of header and footer:
let header = '<h1>Welcome to Our Site</h1>
              <main>'

let footer = '</main>
              <p>Footer</p>'

This doesn't work in app.js:
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: portal.headerHtml}}/>
     <div id="portalMain">
         <AppRoutes/>
     </div>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: portal.footerHtml}}/>

This doesn't put the portal in between the main tag, it renders the header, portal, and footer all on the same level (portal isn't nested).
I tried putting the dangerouslySetInnerHTML in its own component, Refs, createPortal, and the parse function from html-react-parser.
What does work is in index.js setting the innerHTML of the root element and having React just handle the App and not using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in App.js:
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

  rootElement.innerHTML = `
    ${headerHtml}
    <div id="react-root"></div>
    ${footerHtml}
  `;

  const reactRootElement = document.getElementById('react-root');
  const root = createRoot(reactRootElement);

  root.render(<App/>)

There has to be a better way to do this though right? I've been chatting with chatGPT and Claude for hours trying to figure out the best way. It seems like the broken HTML header and footer is making it challenging. It would be great if I could get the portal to be in the correct location and have the header and footer within the React App instead of outside of it.
This is for work. Clients set their own custom HTML and I need the react app injected precisely in-between the header and footer HTML.

Why do your header and footer HTML string snippets include partial tags in the first place?

You can use html-react-parser's replace() feature with a slightly doctored template that has a well-known inner element (a div with the id _react) to replace with your React content:


let header = "<h1>Welcome to Our Site</h1><main>";
let footer = "</main><p>Footer</p>";

function Wrapper({header, footer, inner}) {
  return window.HTMLReactParser(`${header}<div id="_react"></div>${footer}`, {
    replace(element) {
      if(element.attribs && element.attribs.id === "_react") return React.cloneElement(inner);
    }
  });
}


const ReactApp = () => {
  return <div>
    <Wrapper header={header} footer={footer} inner={<h2>React says hi!</h2>} />
  </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<ReactApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-react-parser@latest/dist/html-react-parser.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>



